# Would you kindly undo the rejection of my edit and re-open this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, suggested-edits, request

[This suggested edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1469) for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44155/english-phraseology) was just rejected.  It was an attempt on my part to incorporate the OP's clarification made in [this comment on my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44155/english-phraseology/44160#comment-81219) into the question.

The edit was rejected with this message:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

While I agree that the edit was pretty large, I disagree entirely that it changed the meaning or intent.  The original form of the question is extremely rough; there's no way to improve it without massive change.  But again, all the information I added came from the OP; I merely expressed his intent more clearly, I didn't alter it.

Once the edit was approved I was going to flag the question for re-opening, so please do that too.  Actually I'm not sure whether edit rejections can be undone, so let me know if I need to propose it again.

Comment: Hi Matthew! I was not the one to reject your edit suggestion, but I can easily see how it happened. The edit seems to change the question substantially, and it is not obvious when reviewing the edit that in fact the information came from the OP and you were editing it in. To make that more clear, in future I'd suggest mentioning that in your edit summary, for example, "clarified question based on OP's comment below my answer" which might help whoever reviews the edit see where to look.

Comment: (Of course, you are well on your way to the rep needed to edit questions without approval, too. :) )

Comment: @aedia Oh yeah, I definitely understand what happened.  Hence the nice calm Meta post clarifying things :P.  I have a bad habit of not using edit descriptions at all, I'll have to work on that.

Comment: I will say that I was the one who rejected the edit. When a pending edit appears, it only shows what you see in the suggestion--the current post, and the edit. I felt it was a radical change from the original post. However, considering you based it off a comment (which do not appear in the edit queue), I see why you suggested it and I apologize.

Comment: @simchona No worries! As aedia notes I should have had a better edit description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited the post as you originally suggested. Unfortunately, you don't end up with the credit this way, but there's nothing I can do about that. :/

Comment: No worries, I'm not concerned about the 2 rep or anything :P thanks!